# Content Manager in another class XNA

Tags: xna, content-management

I have created a separate class (let's call it class2.cs for example) and want to use it as a level, in that when I call it, it will draw everything in one level for me. I'm having trouble getting contentmanager to work in class2. In the given Game1.cs, you can easily just go `texture2d= Content.Load<Texture2D>("photo");` but I can't in class2.

I realize I have to create a new Content Manager, but it's constructor requires a game service, in which I'm not sure what I'm suppose to plug in. I currently have: `ContentManager content = new ContentManager();` but I need an overload for ContentManager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass Content to the constructor of your second class from the game, or you can create a Globals.cs class with static variables for your ContentManager or spriteBatch or any common resources.

Comment: Do not use globals - use dependency injection instead (http://www.codeplex.com/unity)

Comment: EDIT: Never mind fixed, I had to load contentmanager after initialize, not as in the constructor.

Comment: @BlueRaja, "pass Content to the constructor of your second class", that is dependency injection, btw